# Объединить метки [vue.js] и [vue]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [vue.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) (58 вопросов) и [vue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue) (18 вопросов) в пользу [vue.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js).

Comment: Вот эти вопросы точно про vue.js? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue+-vue.js+-javascript

Comment: Абсолютно точно.